# I am getting this error while testing in flutter, how can I solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, compiler-errors

> Error: The name 'expect' is defined in the libraries
> 'package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart (via
> package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart)' and
> 'package:test_api/src/expect/expect.dart'. Try using 'as prefix' for
> one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of
> the imports.

Code:

```
testWidgets("TEST WİDGET SUCCESS", (widgetTester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(const MyHomePage(title: 'Ti', mesaj: 'Msg'));

      final titleFind = find.text("Ti");
      final MesajFind = find.text("msg");

      expect(titleFind, findsOneWidget);
      expect(, matcher)
    });
Image:
[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The message means that the function `expect` is defined two times. Once in `widget_tester.dart` and once in `expect.dart`. Because of this it doesn't know which of the two it should use. To solve it you could try leave out one of the import statements if you're not using it for other reasons or as the error message suggest to add `as prefix` That means that you could for example change

```
import 'package:test_api/src/expect/expect.dart';
```

to

```
import 'package:test_api/src/expect/expect.dart' as whateverYouLike;
```

and then where you want to use functions of that file prefix it with that like `whateverYouLike.expect()`

Or for the one that you don't want to use the `expect()` function of you write

```
import 'package:test_api/src/expect/expect.dart' hide expect;
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the function `expect` is defined in two places:

1. flutter_test.dart, and
2. test_api/src/expect/expect.dart

The compiler is confused on which definition to use. Please remove `test_api/src/expect/expect.dart` if it is not required. If it is required, please give it in alias like this:

```dart
import 'package:test_api/src/expect/expect.dart' as test_api
```